# Job for uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: django

Intento desplegar Django en Centos 9 stream. Después de ejecutar

```
sudo systemctl start uwsgi
```

Obtengo el mensaje:

```
Job for uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service


[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown victor:nginx /run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all`

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

No encuentro el motivo de la falla.

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código de arriba, el problema radicaba en la línea:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

Ejecuté `whereis uwsgi` para saber la ruta de uwsgi y el resultado fue `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`.

Así que cambie la línea anterior con la ruta que obtuve:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

Eso resolvió el problema. CentOS 9 tiene una carpeta más (local) en **/usr/**

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.